# Stacking Output From Many Models in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: io, output

I’m doing a series of regression analyses using BlueSky Statistics. There will be one for each level of a factor. I’d like to write the models to a data set so I can sort them by how well they fit the data (R-squared). I can export one at a time to Excel files and stack them manually, but is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

BlueSky Statistics will do this automatically if you make the right choice (hint: don't "split for analysis" by your factor!) Under the Modeling menu, choose "Group By Modeling". That will bring up a dialog that lets you specify the regression model, and your "grouping variable" (your factor). By default the results will go to the output window, so you probably want to click "Enter prefix for data sets" and put in a name for the data sets like, "RegByGroup_". It'll then create three new data sets, at three different levels of aggregation. The one you want would be named, "RegByGroup_Glance_Results". The first column will be named "r_squared" and you can sort it  with "Data> Sort". The data set with "tidy_results" in its name will contain one observation per parameter (t-tests, p-values, etc). The final one, with "augmented_results" will contain the original data set plus measures for every row, such as predicted values and regression diagnostics.